# Display DataSourceResult in Kendo Grid after where clause using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to display filtered data in the grid, but i don't know what exactly is the reason its not getting displayed after monthYearfilter where clause.It binds the data to kendo grid using currentmonthyear but not with monthYearfilter. I have used previously the same functionality in different project and it is running fine.

I do get the data in the DataSourceResult result after linq where clause, but does not gets displayed in the grid.

//Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BillingChecklist_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,string monthYearfilter)
        {


        using (var preemploymentdata = new AREntities())
        {
            IQueryable<BillingCheckList> preEmploymentWorkflows = preemploymentdata.BillingCheckLists;


            DataSourceResult result;




            if (monthYearfilter != null)
            {

                result = preEmploymentWorkflows.Where(x => x.MonthYear == monthYearfilter).ToDataSourceResult(request);
            }
            else  
            {

                 string currentmonthyear = DateTime.Now.Year + "/0" + DateTime.Now.Month;

                 result = preEmploymentWorkflows.Where(x => x.MonthYear == currentmonthyear).ToDataSourceResult(request);
            }



            return Json(result);


        }
    }
```

//View Code

```
@{

   Html.Kendo().Grid<BillingCheckList>()
            .Name("MyGrid")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
                .Ajax() 

   .Read(read => read.Action("BillingChecklist_Read", "BillingChecklist")) 
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.OfficePrefix))
            )



    .Columns(col =>
            {


              col.Bound(o =>.OfficePrefix).Groupable(false).Title("Offices");

                col.Bound(o => o.MonthYear).Title("MonthYear").Visible(false);

                col.Group(group => group
                    .Title("Time Entered & Completed").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
                    .Columns(info =>
                    {
                        info.Bound(o => o.IsTimeWk1).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" })
                            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsTimeWk1 ? checked='checked': '' # onclick='UpdateCheckBox( #= BilingChecklistID #, \"#= OfficePrefix #\",  \"#= 'IsTimeWk1'#\", \"#= IsTimeWk1 #\"  )'/>")
                            .Title("WK<br>1").Width(5);

                        info.Bound(o => o.IsTimeWk2).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" })
                            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  #= IsTimeWk2 ? checked='checked': '' # onclick='UpdateCheckBox( #= BilingChecklistID #, \"#= OfficePrefix #\",  \"#= 'IsTimeWk2'#\", \"#= IsTimeWk2 #\"  )' />")
                            .Title("WK<br>2").Width(5);

                        info.Bound(o => o.IsTimeWk3).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" })
                            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  #= IsTimeWk3 ? checked='checked': '' # onclick='UpdateCheckBox( #= BilingChecklistID #, \"#= OfficePrefix #\",  \"#= 'IsTimeWk3'#\", \"#= IsTimeWk3 #\"  )'/>")
                            .Title("WK<br>3").Width(5);

                        info.Bound(o => o.IsTimeWk4).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" })
                            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  #= IsTimeWk4 ? checked='checked': '' # onclick='UpdateCheckBox( #= BilingChecklistID #, \"#= OfficePrefix #\",  \"#= 'IsTimeWk4'#\", \"#= IsTimeWk4 #\"  )'/>")
                            .Title("WK<br>4").Width(5);

                        info.Bound(o => o.IsTimeWk5).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left" })
                            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  #= IsTimeWk5 ? checked='checked': '' # onclick='UpdateCheckBox( #= BilingChecklistID #, \"#= OfficePrefix #\",  \"#= 'IsTimeWk5'#\", \"#= IsTimeWk5 #\"  )'/>")
                            .Title("WK<br>5").Width(5);
                    }));

})          .Sortable()
            .Render();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are filtering the data server-side, try clearing the filters before returning the DataSourceResult to prevent the data from being filtered again client-side.

```
result.Filters.Clear();

return Json(result);
```